# How do fix urlopen error in Python? Use youtube-dl

Tags: python-3.x, ssl, pyopenssl, youtube-dl

**What to do with this Error**:
***I can't solve this Problem on MacOs ! Nobody can help me ? On Windows it works nice !***

@phihag
**youtube-dl -U :**

```
Updating to version 2017.11.15 ...
```

openssl version -a:

```
OpenSSL 1.0.2m  2 Nov 2017
built on: reproducible build, date unspecified
platform: darwin64-x86_64-cc
options:  bn(64,64) rc4(ptr,int) des(idx,cisc,16,int) idea(int) blowfish(idx)
compiler: clang -I. -I.. -I../include  -fPIC -fno-common -DOPENSSL_PIC -DZLIB_SHARED -DZLIB -DOPENSSL_THREADS -D_REENTRANT -DDSO_DLFCN -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -arch x86_64 -O3 -DL_ENDIAN -Wall -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT5 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DAES_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DBSAES_ASM -DWHIRLPOOL_ASM -DGHASH_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM
OPENSSLDIR: "/usr/local/etc/openssl"
```

**python --version:**

```
Python 2.7.14
```

**python3 --version:**

```
Python 3.6.3
```

**youtube-dl Command:**

```
youtube-dl -v -u myEmail@gmail.com -p myPassword -o '~/Development/tutorials/new/%(playlist)s/%(chapter_number)s - %(chapter)s/%(title)s.%(ext)s'  https://www.udemy.com/react-the-complete-guide-incl-redux/learn/v4/content
```

**Terminal Output:**

```
[debug] System config: []
[debug] User config: []
[debug] Custom config: []
[debug] Command-line args: [u'-v', u'-u', u'PRIVATE', u'-p', u'PRIVATE', u'-o', u'~/Development/tutorials/new/%(playlist)s/%(chapter_number)s - %(chapter)s/%(title)s.%(ext)s', u'https://www.udemy.com/react-the-complete-guide-incl-redux/learn/v4/content']
[debug] Encodings: locale UTF-8, fs utf-8, out UTF-8, pref UTF-8
[debug] youtube-dl version 2017.11.15
[debug] Python version 2.7.14 - Darwin-16.7.0-x86_64-i386-64bit
[debug] exe versions: none
[debug] Proxy map: {}
[udemy:course] Downloading login popup
```

**ERROR:**

```
ERROR: Unable to download webpage: <urlopen error [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:661)> (caused by URLError(SSLError(1, u'[SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:661)'),))
  File "/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl/youtube_dl/extractor/common.py", line 506, in _request_webpage
    return self._downloader.urlopen(url_or_request)
  File "/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py", line 2196, in urlopen
    return self._opener.open(req, timeout=self._socket_timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 429, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 447, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 407, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl/youtube_dl/utils.py", line 1086, in https_open
    req, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1198, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
```

Comment: This is very likely a problem with the remote server. What is the actual URL you're downloading?

Comment: URL: https://www.udemy.com/angular-2-and-nodejs-the-practical-guide/learn/v4/content

I can Download some my paid Courses Manually, but it's very hard to do it.
Would like very much download it with youtube-dl.

Comment: Nobody has an Idea ?

Comment: The URL works fine for me with youtube-dl from multiple locations all over the world. The error indicates one of two things: Either your OpenSSL is terribly outdated (that would probably be a security vulnerability and should never happen), or your ISP is trying to intercept HTTPS requests. So check that `python -c 'import ssl;print(ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION)'` returns something recent like `OpenSSL 1.1.0g  2 Nov 2017`. If this returns an overly old version, use [brew](https://brew.sh/) to get a newer Python. Also try with another ISP to exclude ISP meddling, for instance by using a VPN.

Comment: I installed with brew Python 3 on my MAC, if i type python --version become this result : `Python 2.7.14`, if i try python3 --version show me this: `Python 3.6.3` and here my openssl version:
`Openssl: OpenSSL 0.9.8zh 14 Jan 2016 `

I Have in /.bash_profile setup this:
`export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.1.1ø/bin:$PATH
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin:$PATH"
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH`

Comment: i Update my openssl to `OpenSSL 1.0.2m  2 Nov 2017`

Comment: Great! Does it work with the current OpenSSL? (Make sure to verify you're actually using it!)

Comment: How can i see witch openssl version is currently in use?
If i type openssl version -a become this version `OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016` and for python --version `Python 2.7.14`.
How can i set Python 3 as a default ? I tried with `brew uninstall python` and after than `brew update` `brew upgrade` i solved all conflicts after using  `brew doctor`and install Python 3.6.3 with `brew install python3`
My head is now smoking !

Comment: Can someone help me to solve this Issue on Mac Please? I Edited my Question with currently Information.

Comment: I get the timeout when I'm on my PIA vpn. Any suggestions to work around this to use youtube-dl on a vpn?

Answer (score 3):

Per [phihag's hint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47128086/how-do-fix-urlopen-error-in-python-use-youtube-dl#comment81297633_47128086), your SSL's version is too old.

If you haven't upgraded python, that's a simple solution. However, since your question is tagged python3 and your debug output is talking about python2, it's possible you're not using the latest SSL cert on your system.

I suspect if you use:

```
python3 `which youtube-dl` yoururl
```

then it will work.